# Cracking N Digit Unknown Password

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

Hi I'm quite new to Aircrack-ng and I just have a quick question. Is there a possible way to determine the amount of digits a wifi password has?

In the example below the amount of digits is already known as `12` how would I determine this amount of digits in the case where I don't know the password.

```
crunch 12 12 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 | aircrack-ng -w - -b xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx capture-03.cap
```

> I am doing this to my own router/wifi password. I am testing how quick if at all or partly, I can crack my own WPA2-PSK password without a wordlist.file

---

Second question:

If I add `!@#$%^&*()` to the end of
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`

will those digits be included in the attack? Is there perhaps a better way?

I'm keen on using my gpu to speed up cracking the password.

---

Third question:

Lets say my wifi password is `IL*veMyCat#` Is there perhaps a way to determine certain digits of that password and output them into a file `e.g Output.txt> IL-veMyCat-` Where the missing digits are `* and #`

I have been able to use aircrack-ng successfully on Khali V2, any help, links, advice will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I don't believe you can het the password size. Input is stretched in order to form a password.

Comment: If you can find out what vendor of the router is you can search up informations about the password requirements. That could help you determine the length of the router password.

Comment: It is hard to understand if you are asking questions about password length, charset used in password or digits/numbers that are used in the psk. Voting this question as "unclear".

Comment: Generally, it might be easier to split these three actual questions into three *separate* stackexchange questions.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to determine either the length or certain characters of the password. You can read more about the authentication protocol here to understand why: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i-2004.

For your second question, yes, they will be included in the attack. You can check the manual of crunch to see examples of how it can be used by running: man crunch (I suppose you're using linux)

Your password is pretty strong. I believe it will take forever for any moderate attacker to crack it.

Comment: Thanks I hope to do some more research on the topic. I might even answer myself, who knows :)